# Xaml C# Bind data works only the first time

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

My problem is I use Binding between my view and my data, but it works only the first time, if I update my data after again, my view is not updated. (Windows phone 8)

**View code:**

```
    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="DataContextAction" DataContext="{Binding DataContextAction}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="665" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="471">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HardwareId}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

**xaml.cs page:**

```
public DevicePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Display message waiting before make the http query.
    txtMessage.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    txtMessage.Text = "Loading...";

    // Initialize the view data binding.
    InitializeAsynch();

    // Start new thread in background.
    var refreshViewBackground = new System.Threading.Thread(RefreshViewBackground);
    refreshViewBackground.Start();
}

private async void InitializeAsynch()
{
    // TODO BAD CODE but I don't understand (and I don't have enough time) how make it better. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html
    DataContext = await UserSession.RefreshLastLocationDevices();
    // If I do that now with empty session, the view will be empty.
    //DataContextAction.ItemsSource = UserSession.Actions;
    txtMessage.Text = "";
}
```

When I start a new action I run a new thread which will update the session when the action will be done. (In the same file than previous code)

```
private void StartListenNewAction(DataAction action, DataDevice device)
{
    // Update the actions list;
    try
    {
         DataContextAction.ItemsSource = UserSession.Actions;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to refresh, another thread has updated the action list. " + e.Message);
    }

    // Start new thread in background for this specific action.
    ParameterizedThreadStart refreshActionBackground = new  ParameterizedThreadStart(RefreshActionBackground);
    Thread thread = new Thread(refreshActionBackground);
    Thread.Start(new object[] { action, device });
}
```

But here, only the first time that's works. My view is updated only once.
Thank you for your help, I don't understand, I use another longListSelector and I don't have troubles using the session, but I use directly {Binding}, not the name.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="listDevices" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...
```

So, I don't understand why here it don't works.

**Edit:**
As asked:

```
// Refresh only one action in background.
public async void RefreshActionBackground(object args)
{
    bool pending = true;

    DataAction action = (DataAction)((object[])args)[0];
    DataDevice device = (DataDevice)((object[])args)[1];

    while (pending)
    {
        // Sleep some time.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(device.AskingFrequencyActive * 1000);

        // Get the action from the web service.
        List<Param> parameters = new List<Param>();
        parameters.Add(new Param("email", UserSession.Email));
        parameters.Add(new Param("password", UserSession.Password));
        parameters.Add(new Param("hardwareId", device.HardwareId));// Mandatory.
        parameters.Add(new Param("id", action.Id));
        parameters.Add(new Param("limit", "1"));

        // Send the request.
        IDictionary<string, object> response = await WebService.Send("action", "find", parameters);

        if ((bool)response["status"])
        {
            // Get objects from the response.
            Dictionary<string, object> data = (Dictionary<string, object>)response["data"];
            // We got an array, convert to array.
            JsonArray actionsArray = (JsonArray)data["action"];

            // Update the session.
            actionsArray.ForEach(delegate(dynamic actionJson)
            {
                // Update the action from the session.
                UserSession.Actions.Where(s => (string)s.Id == (string)actionJson["id"]).First().Status = (string)actionJson["status"];

                // Get the action from the session.
                DataAction actionSession = UserSession.Actions.Where(s => s.Id == action.Id).First();

                // Compare to the session which could be updated since the last time.
                if (actionSession.Status == "Executed")
                {
                    pending = false;
                    // Update UI thread.
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        // Update the actions list;
                        try
                        {
                            DataContextAction.ItemsSource = UserSession.Actions;
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to refresh, another thread has updated the action list. " + e.Message);
                        }

                        // Update UI interface.
                        txtMessage.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                        this.txtMessage.Text = "Action executed: " + action.Type;
                    });
                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine((string)response["message"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would offer you to read this - about INotifyPropertyChanged http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Where is `RefreshActionBackground' and `RefreshViewBackground` defined? Can you show it?

Comment: Main post updated. RefreshActionBackground function added.

Comment: Can you please watch this [video about using async void](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-1-Async-void-is-for-top-level-event-handlers-only) methods.

Comment: I will, but it's over, project completed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said the project is over but I figured out how make it works, a bad way actually and absolutely crazy.

It's quite simple, if my listview constains more than one device, it's working. If there is only one, it's not working. Absolutely no idea what's going on and I don't work on it anymore, so it's a trick, maybe will happens to someone else.

The project is hosted on git, here: https://bitbucket.org/Vadorequest/trip-analyzer-server-node.js/overview

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't be using a new thread. You're basically claiming new threads for no good reason until the system runs out of them. Look into using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) instead. Are you sure you're still on the right thread the second time from which the user interface is supposed to be updated?

Comment: In the RefreshActionBackground() function I execute the code which update the UI thread using Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke so I think it's good. In the StartListenNewAction() function I'm in the UI thread. I'll try it anyway. I don't know about Tasks, I use them for my await calls but no more. i don't really have time for update al the application, I didn't knew anything about WP8 view there are 24 hours...